# C# ASP.Net: Read & Rewrite File based on session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website ATM school project, and I need to be able to rewrite the account balance in the original .txt file based on session transactions. The .txt file contains 3 lines, each with (username),(password),(balance). The issue I'm having is that the program cannot write to file while it is still reading it. The loop works fine if I write to a different file, but I have to edit the original (so the updated balance is retained the next time the program is run). Below is the code from the Logout page load event.

```
//Stream variable
StreamReader readFile;
StreamWriter writeFile;

//Counter variable
int index = 0;

//Open file
readFile = File.OpenText(@"C:\C#\Project4_TSullivan\loginFile.txt");

//Array rows
const int ROWS = 3;

while (index < ROWS && !readFile.EndOfStream)
{
    string str = readFile.ReadLine();
    string[] tokens = str.Split(',');

    //Check if username matches session username
    if (tokens[0] == Convert.ToString(Session["sessionUserName"]))
    {
            //Update balance
            tokens[2] = Convert.ToString(Session["sessionBalance"]);
    }

    if (index == 0)
    {
            writeFile = File.CreateText(@"C:\C#\Project4_TSullivan\loginFile.txt");
            writeFile.WriteLine(tokens[0] + "," + tokens[1] + "," + tokens[2]);
            writeFile.Close();
    }
    else
    {
            writeFile = File.AppendText(@"C:\C#\Project4_TSullivan\loginFile.txt");
            writeFile.WriteLine(tokens[0] + "," + tokens[1] + "," + tokens[2]);
            writeFile.Close();
    }
    index++;
}

//Close file
readFile.Close();
```

Please let me know if any additional info would be helpful. I may be going about this in entirely the wrong way, and any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

***Edited***
Here is the solution in case the mods want to save it. Using File.ReadAllLines I was able to store the contents of the file in an array. Then I created 3 more arrays (1 for each line in the file) to tokenize each line.

```
        string path = @"C:\C#\Project4_TSullivan\loginFile.txt";
        string[] readFile = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        string[] token0 = readFile[0].Split(',');
        string[] token1 = readFile[1].Split(',');
        string[] token2 = readFile[2].Split(',');

        if (token0[0] == Convert.ToString(Session["sessionUsername"]))
        {
            token0[2] = Convert.ToString(Session["sessionBalance"]);
        }
        else if (token1[0] == Convert.ToString(Session["sessionUsername"]))
        {
            token1[2] = Convert.ToString(Session["sessionBalance"]);
        }
        else
        {
            token2[2] = Convert.ToString(Session["sessionBalance"]);
        }
        
        using (StreamWriter writeFile = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            writeFile.WriteLine(token0[0] + "," + token0[1] + "," + token0[2]);
            writeFile.WriteLine(token1[0] + "," + token1[1] + "," + token1[2]);
            writeFile.WriteLine(token2[0] + "," + token2[1] + "," + token2[2]);
        }
```

Comment: Read the file contents and close the handle. Ie `IO.File.ReadAllLines(...)` Then process and write the changes.

Comment: @asawyer This worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: You may find it easier to organize your data if instead of 3 arrays you create a single class with 3 properties (you can have the constructor take in a string and parse it and have the .`ToString()` method output the format to go on a line) then hold an array of those classes. Also, I think your updated code is wrong, it is going to pivot the file so every row becomes a column and every column becomes a row.

Comment: The updated code worked perfectly, but I recognize that this is not the best way to go about this (if the .txt file was larger I would have had to create more arrays for each line). I actually do have the file's contents stored in a class array (with properties for the username, password, and balance) from the login page, but I couldn't figure out how to reference it properly to rewrite the file on the logout page.